# Symfony 2 Dependency Injection & autowiring

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm browsing the [Symfony 2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) related to [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html), and can't find a reference to autowiring. I found a [bundle that offers some of this functionality](http://autowiring-bundle.info/), but it's still in beta and seems to be tied to annotations (correct me if I'm wrong).

What I'm looking for is an object (such as the service container), that could inject dependencies in my services, via setter injection.

For example, I would define a Service:

```php
class Service {
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    protected $pdo;

    /**
     * @param \PDO $pdo
     * @Inject
     */
    public function setPDO(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
```

And then, I could use this hypothetical service container to inject dependencies in the Service, even if this one has been created outside the container:

```php
$service = new Service();
// ...

$container->inject($service);
```

Is there a DI container that could autowire dependencies this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Symfony 2.8, autowiring is natively supported: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15613

Answer (score 2):

There is also autowiring bundle aviable at https://github.com/kutny/autowiring-bundle.

Answer (score -1):

See the [`@InjectParams`](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage) annotation from [JMSDiExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle).

Comment: The fact that I answered this question more than 3 years ago doesn't matter, right?

Comment: It just for the newcomers, so they know Symfony has native support for now. And that they don't have to use some bundles. I try to promote most relevant answer up to date.

Comment: Just because something new is coming up more than 3 years after my answer, doesn't make the answer invalid. And the new stuff hasn't even been released yet.

Comment: No argument here. Now there are only more possible solutions to the same problem.